# Localisation issue (Welsh)

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

OK so I have been working on an app that will be available in multiple languages.

I have managed to get it working in the main languages, such as French, German, Spanish and English.

I have also now managed to get the app to use different regions within a language such as en_GB, en_US etc etc so all is good - thanks to this guide:
http://hamishrickerby.com/2010/07/23/iphone-ipad-localizations-regions/

One of the most important languages for me is Welsh. Apple allows me to set my iPhone to welsh by choosing British English as my language and region format as Welsh (United Kingdom).

I have created the Welsh language localisation within my app and translated my bits but I don't seem to be able to apply it.

My idea was that if the users language was set to British English that I could have a button on the main view that would allow the user to chose Welsh. Is this possible and what would be the best way to implement it.

Ideally if the user has already set their language to British english and has the region format to welsh they will get the welsh language version of the app just like the french would automatically get the french language version and the spanish will get the spanish version of the app etc but as most welsh speaking users will have their phone set to United Kingdom as they are not aware of the Welsh Region setting in iOS.

I would like the app to detect if the current language is British English and display a button on the home screen where the user can switch to Welsh Language. I have managed to display this button (only if user language is British English) but have no idea how to link it to change the language?

Anyone have any ideas or maybe a suggestion on the best way to implement my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you've identified, Welsh isn't a fully supported language on iOS. Until Apple supports it properly, you'll have to implement a bit of a workaround.

It seems as though the main solution is to have both English and Welsh `.strings` files (like you would with other languages), but manually load the required language, using

```
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:yourString value:@"" table:@"Welsh"];
```

`@"Welsh"` could be another language there, depending on what you want to load. You'll have to implement some control within your app so that users can change the language themselves. Check out the example project linked to in [this blog post by translation company Applingua](http://applingua.com/supporting-unsupported-languages-in-ios/) - it shows one way of encapsulating this code into a language provider class.

Comment: Wow that is amazing - best answer i have ever had on here! Ha what are the chances of such a accurate answer! brilliant thank you.

Comment: Hi James, what about images - using different images for welsh?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that one. Ideally, you'd avoid having to have different images for different languages in the first place... Otherwise, perhaps an extension to the string retrieval class in the code I linked to - you could have an `image:forLanguage:` method that returns the named image, suffixed with `_Welsh` or `_English`, for example?

Comment: Hi James, I have now managed to get the image working so that is all good. I have one more question, is there a way that you can think of if the user changes the language to Welsh that Welsh will then be the default language for the user every time the app loads moving forward instead of it reverting back to english every time? This would be very useful

Comment: I'd just store the language selection in NSUserDefaults - it's the easiest way to persist settings data like that. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Welsh" forKey:@"Language"]` or similar, and then read it back with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Language"]`.

Comment: Hi Dan. I've answered your original question above - I'd recommend opening a new question if you need help on a different issue (it'll help you get extra responses, and help other people searching in the future). Thanks.